# mysql row number is not working properly with order

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, rowid

I have a Store Database with the following tables :

1 - Provider(**ProviderID**,Name,Country)

2 - Product(**ProductID**,ProviderID,ProductPrice)

3 - Command(**CommandID,ProductID**,ProductQuantity,CommandDate)

I made a query that counts the gain by year

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM COMMAND_DATE) AS year, 
SUM(PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY) AS gain
FROM PRODUCT JOIN COMMAND ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID=COMMAND.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year
```

This is the output :

[image]

Now I want to display the row number just like Oracle, so I used this query :

```
SET @currentRow = 0;
SELECT @currentRow := @currentRow + 1 AS counter,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM COMMAND_DATE) AS year,
SUM(PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY) AS gain
FROM PRODUCT JOIN COMMAND ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID=COMMAND.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year
```

But I don't get what I want

[image]

It seems that order is affecting the row number. I want it to start from 1. Ordering by counter is not an option because I need to order by years.

This is how I want it to be :

```
1 2014 1863
2 2015 889
3 2016 2626
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `group by`, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT (@currentRow := @currentRow + 1) AS counter, y.*
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM COMMAND_DATE) AS year,
             SUM(PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY) AS gain
      FROM PRODUCT JOIN
           COMMAND
           ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = COMMAND.PRODUCT_ID
      GROUP BY year
      ORDER BY year
     ) y CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @currentRow := 0) params;
```

Or, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR)`, if you are using MySQL 8+.